# CLabel windows builder image issue

Tags: eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

[image]

I am trying to add an image in a CLabel using windows builder for Eclipse. The image I have saved in classpath and technically it should show but its not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    lblNewLabel.setOpaque(true);
```

It looks like you assigned the image to the label correctly, but the label needs to be opaque in order for you to see the image that is assigned to it. Hope that helps!